Removing circle from outputlayer in neuralnetwork library
I made the graph

using the following code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}

\begin{document}
    \begin{neuralnetwork}[height=5]
        
        \newcommand{\x}[2]{$X_#2$}
        
        \newcommand{\fx}[2]{$f\left(X\right)$}

        
        \newcommand{\y}[2]{$Y$}
        
       
        \inputlayer[count=4, bias=false, title=Input\\Layer, text=\x]
        
        
        \outputlayer[count=1,  title=Output\\Layer, text=\fx] \linklayers

        \outputlayer[count=1,  title=,  text=\y] \linklayers

        
    \end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}

I want to remove the circle from the last outputlayer Y and want to move it to left. Any hints!

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}

\tikzset{foo/.style={output neuron,fill=none,xshift=-1cm}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{neuralnetwork}[height=5]
        
        \newcommand{\x}[2]{$X_#2$}
        
        \newcommand{\fx}[2]{$f\left(X\right)$}

        
        \newcommand{\y}[2]{$Y$}
        
       
        \inputlayer[count=4, bias=false, title=Input\\Layer, text=\x]
        
        
        \outputlayer[count=1,  title=Output\\Layer, text=\fx] \linklayers

        \outputlayer[count=1,  title=,  text=\y, nodeclass={foo}] \linklayers

        
    \end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}



-or fill=none

@hpekristiansen Good idea, that's probably more robust. Thanks!
